# Adding image to richeditable textarea is not working

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

I am trying to add an image to my textarea .Everything is fine but i am not getting why this code not works.

Here is my text area(mxml)::

```
<s:RichEditableText id="insultTxtArea" x="0" y="0" width="90%" height="100%"
                                        color="#000000"  
                                        editable="false" fontFamily="Helvetica" selectable="true" 
                                        textFlow="{TextConverter.importToFlow( insultTxtArea.text, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT )}"

                                        styleName="customStyle"

                                        textAlign="left" textDecoration="none"/>
```

I am adding an image

```
insultTxtArea.text = "<img src='assets\\insult500.png'>";
```

But where the fault is???
Thanks in advance

Comment: check if path is correct, try with forward shash

Comment: Nope,Its not workign then also. Its displaying simple text @amit

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
insultTxtArea.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow("your html string", 
          TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
```

Comment: I have already tried this.But htmlText showing an error as undefined property @amit

Comment: i made some edit,, check it works now (sorry i did not saw ur code properly, i thought it was normal text area)

Comment: Once see my RichEditableText  component in my code. I have already implemented that. But it still not working. @amit

Comment: sorry, got no idea.. you can try this: http://flexdevtips.blogspot.de/2010/10/displaying-html-text-in-labels.html  , this guy overrided the 'text' method.. hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<s:RichEditableText id="insultTxtArea">
        <s:textFlow>
            <s:TextFlow>
                <s:img source="assets/insult500.png" width="auto" height="auto" />
            </s:TextFlow>
        </s:textFlow>
    </s:RichEditableText>
```

Comment: Alternately you can mention textflow in the actionscriptcode itself as below:-                                                insultTxtArea.textFlow = TextFlowUtil.importFromString('<img source="assets/insult500.png"/>');